# How to find the greatest and smallest integers that satisfy abc.....n =a^3 + b^3 ......... + n^3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. I have been stuck on this problem for a long time. Please help. I am able to get the sum of the cubes of all the digits but I am not able to find the smallest and largest integer values that satisfy the relation

my code:

```
list1 = [int(x) for x in input("enter the number")
list3 = [ i**3 for i in list1]
b = sum(list3)
```

i want to find the smallest and largest values that satisfy x = b

Comment: Would you share your code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be referring to [**Armstrong Numbers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) (Also known as **Narcissistic Numbers**):

> In "A Mathematician's Apology", G. H. Hardy wrote:
>
> > *There are just four numbers, after unity, which are the sums of the cubes of their digits:*
> >
> > [image]

To generate these numbers in your code, you can simply place a loop:

```
max = 10000
for n in range(1,max):
    list1 = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
    list3 = [ i**3 for i in list1]
    b = sum(list3)
    if (n==b):
        print(n)
```

This will produce:

```
1
153
370
371
407
```

I am not sure if it was mathematically proven that 407 is the largest number that is the sum of its digits' cubes.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as with `n` included you need to run over infinite numbers and compare to get smallest and largest number.

if you have a set of numbers to try out the equation, you can have a separate array of numbers that satisfy the equation and then use `min(array)` and `max(array)` to get the smallest and largest number.

please share your current work if the answer doesn't satisfy your needs.

Comment: thanks for the reply! i have edited my statement. please the code that i have written and guide me on how to approach this problem